# Can I use a touch screen from an old Blackberry on a Raspberry PI?

Tags: raspberry-pi, lcd, touchscreen, oled

I have a pile of old Blackberry phones with capacitive touch screens and I'm hoping they can be reused as, at the very least, output devices for Raspberry PIs or even microprocessors.

Is this even a thing?

What specs / properties should I be aware of in order to determine the viability of any of these screens as output devices for Raspberry PI etc?

Comment: Maybe, but it all depends on whether you can identify the connectors.

Comment: You first have to check whether the touch controller is connected to the screen assembly or built into the Blackberry itself. If the latter, forget it. If the former, it's worth the effort only if the controller is one of those supported by the Linux kernel OOTB.